# Does nesting a FileInputStream in a BufferedInputStream create a memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

If I create my BufferedInputStream via…

```
FileInputStream fos = new FileInputStream(FILE_TO_READ);
BufferedInputSteam bos new BufferedInputSteam(fos);
…
bos.close();
fos.close();
```

I can close the FileInputStream explicitly.  But if I create it nested…

```
BufferedInputSteam bos new BufferedInputSteam(new FileInputStream(FILE_TO_READ));
…
bos.close();
```

I can not close the FileInputStream explicitly.

Is this a memory leak?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe so. According to the Java Documention found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#close%28%29)

> Closes this file input stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream.
>
> If this stream has an associated channel then the channel is closed as well.

Answer (score 0):

`InputStream` classes are based on the Decorator Pattern so no memory issue, it will be properly closed.

You just have to close the top level `InputStream`

```
bos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't close the underlying input stream, because the `BufferedInputSteam` closes it for you. It's meant to be a convenience and it's only reasonable. Think about it, *why should you be allowed access to the underlying `FileInputStream`, independently of the `BufferedInputSteam` that encapsulates it? Such access will likely allow you to break the `BufferedInputSteam`.

Trying to close an already closed stream will give you an `IOException: Stream already closed` exception anyway